# How to get next node to be iterated in an XSLT for-each loop?

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

If I have a for each loop such as:

```
<xsl:for-each select="$pChildren">
    <xsl:variable name="vNext" select="???" />
</xsl:for-each>
```

I am trying to assign the next node to be iterated in the for-each loop to `vNext`, if any.

I tried `$pChildren[position()+1]` but did not work.

Comment: It depends on how you defined `$pChildren`. In most cases it will be `following-sibling::*[1]`, but it is not all certain.

Comment: Why did `$pChildren[position()+1]` not work? It looks right and is more general than `following-sibling::*[1]`. Can you add some context?

Comment: @nwellnhof It did not work because `[position()+1]` is short for `[position() = position()+1]`which will never be true.

Comment: the "position()" in the predicate will refer to the position of the item being tested, not the current position in the loop. You have to store the current position in a variable first and then use that stored variable for testing, as michael has done in his answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would prefer to answer this while seeing the entire context, but I believe:

```
<xsl:for-each select="$pChildren">
    <xsl:variable name="i" select="position()" />
    <xsl:variable name="vNext" select="$pChildren[$i + 1]" />
</xsl:for-each>
```

should work for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to reference the next item in a sequence, you probably shouldn't be using a xsl:for-each statement in the first place. Reverse the order of the nodes and use xsl:iterate (unless you are making major use of multi-threading).

A more natural way to do this is:

```
<xsl:iterate select="reverse($pchildren)">
<xsl:param name="last" select="()"/>

Do Stuff Here using $last to reference the item that comes next in $pchildren.
<xsl:next-iteration>
<xsl:with-param name="last" select="."/>
</xsl:next-iteration>
</xsl:iterate/>
```